# Pass a json object in function as a variable

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop which I would like to pass the object in a function.

```
forExample(item[i]);
```

However, when viewing the HTML of the javascript, it is being passed as `forExample('[object Object]')` and not what I would expect `forExample('{"hello":"world","good":"day"}')`

I can pass each item in as its own variable, but that can be clunky and quite messy. If something like that possible (pass in the object)?

Code:

```
collections += "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#editModal\" style=\"background: #cccccc; border: 0; color: black;\" onclick=\"showEditModalCode('"+JSON.stringify(text.items[i])+"')\">EDIT CARD</button>";
```

So, although it is working as expected, when I click on the button to print out an item from the array, I get an error. I believe this is because its being sent as example('{"key":"value"}') and the inner quotations are throwing it all off.

Here is the actual HTML

```
onclick="showEditModalCode('{"random":"f92879-5aaf0d4fc08bd7f7958d-f1"}')"
```

Here is the function.

```
function showEditModalCode(item){
  const obj = JSON.parse(item);
  console.log(obj);
}
```

Comment: Could you share the rest of your code, like the array you are iterating

Comment: @letsCode could you also share your item array

Comment: *forExample('{"hello":"world","good":"day"}')* this is actually an string and not an object. When you use stringify for serialisation that doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get [object Object] is because it's a string representation of an object. What you are looking for is JSON.stringify() which converts the object into a string.

```
forExample(JSON.stringify(item[i]));
```

Docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: updated my question. as this works and creates the proper HTML, it does not work when the button is pressed. I think the issue is because it's creating quotations inside of the function.

Comment: what does showEditModalCode do?
you have to revert the string to an js-object. 
``` showEditModalCode(param) { const obj = JSON.parse(param) }```

Comment: i updated question. right now, all i have it doing is printing the object so I know it can get passed properly.

Comment: i updated question. right now, all i have it doing is printing the object so I know it can get passed properly.

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: when the button is pressed, this is the error. (index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input . it should show a modal (which is does), but still an error on btn click

Comment: I think that your issue is that you are generating the HTML. This isn't the best approach

Comment: the reason why I am doing this is because I am getting a response from the server. and I am doing this inside of the response and then appending the text inside of a div.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you pass a string and not an object

```
forExample('{"hello":"world","good":"day"}')
```

Just pass the object and it should work as expected

```
forExample({"hello":"world","good":"day"})
```

To render it in the html then stringify it

```
 JSON.stringify(obj);
```

```js
forExample({
  "hello": "world",
  "good": "day"
});

function forExample(obj) {
  document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work if he renders the object in HTML

Comment: True, my point was that the *object* was far more a string, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve this problem. The first one would be to not construct an HTML string, but instead create JavaScript [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)s and assign attributes there, this removes the need to stringify the object altogether.

This is done by creating the element using:

```
const button = document.createElement("button");
```

Then set all the properties accordingly.

```js
// mock
const text = { items: [{"random":"f92879-5aaf0d4fc08bd7f7958d-f1"}] };
const i = 0;
function showEditModalCode(item) {
  console.log(item);
}

// solution
const button = document.createElement("button");
button.type = "button";
button.className = "btn btn-primary";
button.dataset.toggle = "modal";
button.dataset.target = "#editModal";
button.style.background = "#cccccc";
button.style.border = "0";
button.style.color = "black";
button.onclick = function () { showEditModalCode(text.items[i]) };
button.append("EDIT CARD");
document.body.append(button);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#modal-components -->
<div id="editModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use a HTML string you have to make sure you escape the [HTML characters with special meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents). This can be done by passing the dynamic attribute values to an escape function, that escapes these characters.

```
function escapeHTML(unsafe) {
  const replacements = {
    '"': "&quot;",
    "'": "&apos;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    "&": "&amp;",
  };
  return unsafe.replace(/["'<>&]/g, char => replacements[char]);
}
```

```js
// mock
const text = { items: [{"random":"f92879-5aaf0d4fc08bd7f7958d-f1"}] };
const i = 0;
function showEditModalCode(item) {
  console.log(item);
}

// solution
function escapeHTML(unsafe) {
  const replacements = {
    '"': "&quot;",
    "'": "&apos;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    "&": "&amp;",
  };
  return unsafe.replace(/["'<>&]/g, char => replacements[char]);
}

const html = `
  <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#editModal"
    style="background: #cccccc; border: 0; color: black;"
    onclick="showEditModalCode(${escapeHTML(JSON.stringify(text.items[i]))})"
  >
    EDIT CARD
  </button>
`;

$("#btn-container").html(html);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="btn-container"></div>

<!-- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#modal-components -->
<div id="editModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```